# How to determine the number of nilpotent $3\times 3$ matrices over $\mathbb F_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've read that it equals, upto conjugation, the number of partitions of 3. Is that irrespective of the base field? In that case, shouldn't there be 4 nilpotent matrices over $\mathbb F_2$, upto conjugation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An $n \times n$ matrix (over any field) is nilpotent iff it is similar to a matrix in Jordan canonical fo rm where all diagonal elements are $0$.  We may assume wlog that the sizes of the Jordan blocks are, say, nondecreasing.  The
sizes of the Jordan blocks give you the correspondence to partitions.  In the $3 \times 3$ case, there are $3$ partitions of $3$: $3$, $2+1$, $1+1+1$, corresponding to the following matrices:

$$ \pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr},\
\pmatrix{0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr},\
\pmatrix{0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0\cr}$$